# How to disable some warnings in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, file-upload

in my app i can upload files (max size is 10MB). I created an exception handler for too big files, but console still shows warning that there was a try to upload too big file:

```
2020-09-30 01:38:59.306  WARN 2476 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.MaxUploadSizeExceededException: Maximum upload size exceeded; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (26937892) exceeds the configured maximum (10485760)]
```

Exception handler:

```
    @ExceptionHandler(MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class)
    public void oversizedFilesHandler(MaxUploadSizeExceededException e){
        accountService.writeExceptionToFile(e);
    }
```

Is it possible to disable these warnings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that by adding log level to your properties file:

**RULE :** `logging.level.xxxx=LEVEL`

where:

- **LEVEL** is one of **TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, OFF**.
- **xxxx** is a package/class.

We apply the rule to your case:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=ERROR
```

Or even thinner:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web.multipart =ERROR
```

Hence, only ERROR, FATAL and OFF level will be logged to you console.